# what diffrence between override method and general method in kotlin?

Tags: function, kotlin

[image: Screen Shot]

```
val showMethod:(String) -> Unit = this::showLoadingDialog
override fun start(msg: String) = showMethod
```

I want to use start method = this::showLoadingDialog ,
but get a compile error! the method is not a subtype of overridden ***!

why? how can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is incorrect because `start` is not a variable but it is a function.

```
override fun start(msg: String) = showMethod
```

is equivalent to

```
override fun start(msg: String) {
    return showMethod
}
```

which is incorrect. `start` should return `Unit` instead of `(String) -> Unit`

What you are trying to do is

```
override fun start(msg: String) {
    return showMethod(msg)
}
```

is equivalent to

```
override fun start(msg: String) = showMethod(msg)
```

Comment: fun start2(msg: String) = this::showLoadingDialog，I write this method , compile ok ! there is no `override` !

Comment: @Mugong This is because `start` require a return type of `Unit` and you override it, it cannot be changed. `start2` is not a override function. If you mouse over `start2`, you can see the return type is `KFunction0<Unit>` because Kotlin can detect the type for you even you did not write it. If you state `fun start2(msg: String): Unit = this::showLoadingDialog`, then there will be error.

Comment: thanks ! I know ! no `override ` kotlin use Type inference determine the result type!

Comment: @Mugong Well, almost in every language if you override a function, it needs to have same arguments and return the same type. Also, please mark this as answer if it solved your problem. :)